# Can I link a model in Revit to Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, revit

Well I have created a model of a house using REVIT software. Now I want to use this model in Unity.Is this possible or not!
Like to make it move or like create a character and let it walk in the house. So can I link this house model created in REVIT software with unity software and be able to manipulate it.

Comment: That software is made for construction and I am sure the model it generates is heavy. You can but  you should make sure to clean the model up in another application before importing it. I suggest you use a 3D software made for this such as Blender, Maya or 3dsMax.

Comment: @Programmer the OP is mentioning a model of a "house". I am not sure how big such a model is, but it's not half a city type of model, so I am pretty sure Unity will be fine even with a dirty Revit model. Modern hardware should be able to handle a "house" pretty easy.

Comment: @konrad Like I said in my comment, this is possible and I encouraged OP to import this into another 3D app to clean it up before bringing it into Unity. It doesn't matter if this is one house or not. *There is a poly count limit in Unity for each model*. You forgot that a single house can have other parts like doors, windows, screws and a simple detailed screw can add so many polys when combined. Not to mention that you can't transfer high detailed map to low poly object in Revit. That's because it's not meant for this.

Comment: @Programmer oh no question. You are totally right.

Answer (score 0):

Unity allows for importing of various geometry types. You can export the Revit model to FBX or OBJ file format and that should allow you to import it into Unity. Here's a link explaining the process in Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectMax.html

Here's a link explaining export process for Revit: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-C8038EFE-FB14-4591-85A1-8407B2BDDD0A-htm.html